# How to remove the transition effect from the VuetifyJS Vertical Stepper?

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, stepper

Is it possible to show the next step directly after clicking continue within the [Vuetify Stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#example-vertical)? (or in other words: how to remove the transition slide out effect)

Comment: Searching for this too! Looks like there is a `computedTransition:"v-tab-reverse-transition"` on the `VStepperContent` - but there is no way to change it AFAIK

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is any provided option to change the transition effect in the [Vue component itself](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers).

But, you can disable it by setting the `transition` css property to `none` for the `.stepper-content` elements.

For example, you could create a `no-transition` class:

```
.no-transition .stepper__content { transition: none; }
```

And then add it to the `<v-stepper>` component tag:

```
<v-stepper v-model="e1" class="no-transition">
  ...
</v-stepper>
```

[Here's a codepen with a working example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxRwoW)

Answer (score 6):

Mine worked with

```
.no-transition .v-stepper__content { transition: none; }
```

In case somebody didn’t succeed with @thanksd's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
.v-stepper__wrapper {
  transition:none !important;
}
```

Vuetify version 2.2.8

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the Vuetify stepper transition:

   .v-stepper__content, .v-overlay {
   transition: none !important;
   }
2. Remove the Vuetify stepper transition **only from stepper-header** (which I was looking for). I added a class "stepper-body" to :

   .stepper-body {
   position: relative;
   }