# Custom transition effect between stepper panels

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

With a vuetify [stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers), the default transition effect seems to be `slide-x-transition`. Adding the transition prop (`transition="fade-transition"`) to this component doesn't seem to have any effect- is there any way to override the default animation?

Please see my simple jfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/98mprice/nyqr8ca7/)

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315624/how-to-remove-the-transition-effect-from-the-vuetifyjs-vertical-stepper), accepted answer therein indicates that it wasn't possible.

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I didn't find that post earlier when Google searching :)